# Carousel Slider not changing Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Image slider not working when i click on the arrows or when i try to manually change the image.

With my limited knowledge, i tried editing the code with no luck

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300,100">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

<div class="container" id="slider"><!-- Container Starts -->

  <div class="col-md-12"><!-- col-md-12 Starts -->

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"><!-- carousel slide Starts -->

    <ol class="carousel-indicators"><!-- carousel-indicators Starts -->

      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>

      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>

      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>

      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>

    </ol><!-- carousel-indicators Ends -->

  <div class="carousel-inner"><!-- carousel-inner Starts -->

    <div class="item-active">
      <img src="admin_panel/slides_images/1.jpg" alt="slide 1">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="admin_panel/slides_images/2.jpg" alt="slide 2">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="admin_panel/slides_images/3.jpg" alt="slide 3">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="admin_panel/slides_images/4.jpg" alt="slide 4">
    </div>

  </div><!-- carousel-inner Ends -->

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><!-- left carousel-control Starts -->

  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"> </span>

  <span class="sr-only"> Previous </span>

  </a><!-- left carousel-control Ends -->

  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><!-- right carousel-control Starts -->

  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"> </span>

  <span class="sr-only"> Next </span>

  </a><!-- right carousel-control Ends -->


</div><!-- carousel slide Ends -->

  </div><!-- col-md-12 Ends -->

  </div><!-- Container Ends -->



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The slider is supposed to change when i click on the arrow or try and change it manually. No errors appear, just not the expected result.

Comment: Fixed the issue. Changed this <div class="item-active"> to <div class="item active">. Could someone please explain why? Before it would stay fixed on one image.

Answer (score 0):

**Use The Below Code**

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300,100">
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
> <div class="container">
> <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
> <!-- Indicators -->
> <ol class="carousel-indicators">
>      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
>      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
>      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
>      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
>   </ol>
>   <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
>   <div class="carousel-inner">
>      <div class="item active">
>         <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" alt="slide 1" style="width:100%;">
>      </div>
>      <div class="item">
>         <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="slide 2" style="width:100%;">
>      </div>
>      <div class="item">
>         <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="slide 3" style="width:100%;">
>      </div>
>      <div class="item">
>         <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/30/16/06/water-lily-3784022__340.jpg" alt="slide 4">
>      </div>
>   </div>
>   <!-- Left and right controls -->
>   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
>   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
>   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
>   </a>
>   <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
>   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
>   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
>   </a>
>   </div>
> </div>
> <!-- Container Ends -->
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```